# Synapse Query from Delta Lake Databricks with SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I would to know if there are any way to **query** table **Delta** format from blob container that was created using **Databricks** with **SSMS** or **Azure Data Studio** which is SSMS are connected to Azure Synapse, I've tried to query with this query

```sql
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://blob_container_storage.blob.core.windows.net/delta-lake/test/', FORMAT = 'DELTA') as rows
```

From above query I got an error like this

```
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 188
Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'.
```

So, I want to ask, Is it possible to query delta lake from synapse using SSMS or Azure Data Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Check out this article for details:
[Query Delta Lake files (preview) using serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-delta-lake-format)

Please make sure that you are [connecting to built-in serverless pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/connect-overview#serverless-sql-pool)
as this isn't supported in dedicated pools yet.

Comment: Then, what's wrong with my query ? why I got an error like that ? Because if it refers to your link, it was using query on Synapse Analytics

Comment: Please make sure that you are connecting to built-in serverless pool as this isn't supported in dedicated pools yet. See the second link explaining where to get the connection string...

Comment: So basically, dedicated pool can't query any external resources ? or only Delta format that can't be accessed ?

Comment: There are two things here... Dedicated pool does not support queries over files directly, using OPENROWSET statement, hence the syntax error. It also does not support Delta format. It does support queries over external resources by using external tables. See details here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated